# Building custom angular filter that filters by name

Tags: html, angularjs, filter, angular-filters

I am following this tutorial:

> http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/a-step-by-step-guide-to-your-first-angularjs-app

In my controller, I have this function:

```
$scope.searchFilter = function (driver) {
    var keyword = new RegExp($scope.nameFilter, 'i');
    return !$scope.nameFilter || keyword.test(driver.Driver.givenName) || keyword.test(driver.Driver.familyName);
};
```

In my html, I have this line:

```
<tr ng-repeat="driver in driversList | filter: searchFilter">
```

And in my search bar in the html, I have this line:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" placeholder="Search..."/>
```

What is this doing in the searchFilter function:

```
return !$scope.nameFilter
```

Is it to account for when I type in nothing in the search bar? IF so, how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `$scope.nameFiler == ''`  (or null, undefined)

searchFilter will returns `true`

so, when user doesn't type anything in search box the filter should return all items.